# Python not writing full string to file

Tags: python, file-io, dictionary, sequence, truncation

I am attempting to output an aligned protein sequence to a file, however, the output string is truncated each time I attempt to write the string to file. The string I'm attempting to write is 4603 characters long, and is printed to the console with the correct number of characters. The first snippet of code I'm attaching pertains to the output variable itself. I'm going to include the full strings here, because the way in which the strings are truncated upon writing to a file have been reproducible for me.

```
out=open('out.7.9.12.txt','a+')

score_dict={}
Max='1ZER'
al1='XMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDLDVXXXVNMXFVXXXIXXXXAXXGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXGTLAIXXXXXXXPILAFVXAXXXXXXXXXXXSXXXXXXXXFLLXXXXXWPSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXALXXIRIYXYWYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXWRRTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXLGMQVRYXXXXXXXXXXXXVHHXXEXDYQXFCYSXXXXXFRGXXRPXGXHXXKXXXPSILXXMLHXGXXXFSAHKDMWXXXXXXLSVXXXXXXXXXVXXKXFLPKNLXXXHLVCXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXVDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXMPXXGHXXXEXGTTRSXXXXXXXXXXSLXXXXDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDLSIDGQXVKRIHQFXXXXXXXXXXXVXEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXCXXLXKXLXNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXPFXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXHLVXXXGTSMGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXGQXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXVXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAXXGXXVYAAYYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXPSDVSSLXXCLXVXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXCXXPXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAXXXXXGLXQXXXXYSXTDXXXNQFXXVXXXQRXXXXLXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXELQGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXSAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXVXXEKIXXXXPXXXXLIPSTPEXXEMSXEMLXXXXQXXLCXXXSXYXVXXXXXRFXKVPXQXXXXXXXXQIXLQXGXLVDVXXRXXIXPXXXHNXNXXFYRKXLXXXFLXXXXXXXXEIXVXSEXXXXXXKXXSXXXXXRYSXLXXXHXQNMXXXDKIXXXXXXXXXXKVXPTQXXIXXIWXXXXGXXXKQDXXXQVLXXDVXXXXSGADMLXXAKXXXSIAXNCQVXXEXXLXLEXXNCGXHSVVMEXRPRXXXKXTAKLXXIIDFLASVHNTDNNKKLDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

score_dict[Max]=al1

for name,sequence in score_dict.items():
            out.write('>')
            out.write(name)
            out.write('\n')
            for line in score_dict[name]:
                    out.write(line)
            out.write('\n')
```

With this code snippet, the output to the file should be equal to al1. However, the output to the file is as follows:

```
XMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDLDVXXXVNMXFVXXXIXXXXAXXGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXGTLAIXXXXXXXPILAFVXAXXXXXXXXXXXSXXXXXXXXFLLXXXXXWPSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXALXXIRIYXYWYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXWRRTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXLGMQVRYXXXXXXXXXXXXVHHXXEXDYQXFCYSXXXXXFRGXXRPXGXHXXKXXXPSILXXMLHXGXXXFSAHKDMWXXXXXXLSVXXXXXXXXXVXXKXFLPKNLXXXHLVCXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXVDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXMPXXGHXXXEXGTTRSXXXXXXXXXXSLXXXXDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDLSIDGQXVKRIHQFXXXXXXXXXXXVXEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXCXXLXKXLXNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXPFXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXHLVXXXGTSMGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXGQXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXVXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAXXGXXVYAAYYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXPSDVSSLXXCLXVXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXCXXPXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAXXXXXGLXQXXXXYSXTDXXXNQFXXVXXXQRXXXXLXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXELQGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXSAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXVXXEKIXXXXPXXXXLIPSTPEXXEMSXEMLXXXXQXXLCXXXSXYXVXXXXXRFXKVPXQXXXXXXXXQIXLQXGXLVDVXXRXXIXPXXXHNXNXXFYRKXLXXXFLXXXXXXXXEIXVXSEXXXXXXKXXSXXXXXRYSXLXXXHXQNMXXXDKIXXXXXXXXXXKVXPTQXXIXXIWXXXXGXXXKQDXXXQVLXXDVXXXXSGADMLXXAKXXXSIAXNCQVXXEXXLXLEXXNCGXHSVVMEXRPRXXXKXTAKLXXIIDFLASVHNTDNNKKLDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Pasting these two sequences into a word processor and counting the characters will show that the first has 4603 characters and the second has 4090 characters.

I apologize for the sequence blocks here, but I'm not sure how else I could have accurately represented this problem.

EDIT: The code should now work (I fixed the buffer problem and the quotations issue)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you [closing](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=flush#file.close) the file at the end? It may be that some of your data sits in the buffer, so it is good to [close()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=flush#file.close) the file when you are done (or [flush()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=flush#file.flush) it if you don't want to close it for some reason).

Better yet, to use the `with` construct which will close the file for you when you are done or an exception occurs:

```
with open('out.7.9.12.txt','a+') as out:
   # the rest of your code indented under here
   # ....
   score_dict={}
   Max=245
```

Note from the [flush()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=flush#file.flush) docs:

> **Note** flush() does not necessarily write the file’s data to disk. Use
>   flush() followed by [os.fsync()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fsync) to ensure this behavior

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you for your help. the flush command was well suited for my purpose here.

Comment: I keep yelling at people to close their files, so I find it hilarious that I ended up on here. God bless

Answer (score 5):

Use out.flush() at the end (or close() ) to clear buffers.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `out.close()` at the end of your script. It will ensure that all your output gets flushed to the file.

Also, 'a+' is redundant; 'a' is append-mode which is already writeable.

```
Max = '245'
al1 = 'XMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ...'
scores = {Max:[al1]}

with open('out.7.9.12.txt', 'a') as outf:
    for name,data in scores.iteritems():
        outf.write('>{}\n{}\n'.format(name, '\n'.join(data)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. I've made the change to 'a' and have ensured that I flushed my data to file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was having this exact issue. I found that I neglected to call close as a method. I was using foo.close instead of foo.close().

That resolved it.

Comment: Thank you! totally overlooked the parenthesis.