# file output error with correct values

Tags: python, file, list

My goal is to print out the index of makeList on to another file. I have check my start and end values, which came out correct. However, my outputFile is totally off because it only print one character on that file.

```
def printOutput(start, end, makeList):
  if start == end == None:
      return
  else:
      while start <= end:
          print start
          print end
          outputFile = open('out'+uniprotID+'.txt','w')#file for result output
          inRange = makeList[start]
          start += 1
          outputFile.write(inRange)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the line:

```
outputFile = open('out'+uniprotID+'.txt','w')#file for result output
```

to the line before the while loop. Right now it is reopening the file (as a completely new, empty file) on every single iteration of the while loop.

So the code would be:

```
def printOutput(start, end, makeList):
  if start == end == None:
      return
  else:
      outputFile = open('out'+uniprotID+'.txt','w')#file for result output
      while start <= end:
          print start
          print end
          inRange = makeList[start]
          start += 1
          outputFile.write(inRange)
```

ETA: There is a much easier way to do this using list slicing:

```
def printOutput(start, end, makeList):
  if start == end == None:
      return
  else:
      outputFile = open('out'+uniprotID+'.txt','w')#file for result output
      for inRange in makeList[start:end+1]:
          outputFile.write(inRange)
```

Comment: @DavidRobinson I check makeList index value and output file, it didnt came out right. I print index of make list +1 of the actual value of the index even when i switch the order of outputFile.write(inRange) and start +=1. do you know why is this happen?

Comment: In what way did it not come out right- what was the output? For one thing, you won't have a newline separating each of the values in the output unless you change the code to `outputFile.write(inRange + "\n")`. Also, see my edit for a much simpler version of the code.

Comment: so for example my start value is 10 and end value is 20. However in the outputfile it print makeList[11]makeList[12]...until makeList[21]

Comment: Could you give a reproducible example? Provide an example list and its output? Also, try the simpler version I posted above

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you open the file for writing several times. Basically, this makes the program overwrite the file in each iteration of the `while` loop.

To minimally modify your code, open your file with the `'a'` flag instead of the `'w'` flag. This opens the file in `append` mode instead of `overwrite` mode.

However, this will make your code repeatedly open the file, which will cause it to slow down as disk I/O operations take time. Instead, a better way to do this would be to open the file for writing outside the `while` loop and just write to it inside. In code:

```
def printOutput(start, end, makeList):
    if start == end == None:
        return
    else:
        outputFile = open('out'+uniprotID+'.txt','w')#file for result output
        while start <= end:
            print start
            print end
            inRange = makeList[start]
            start += 1
            outputFile.write(inRange)
        outputFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as already stated, was that the output file was being repeatedly opened inside the loop. The fix is to open the output file *before* you enter the loop.

Here's one more version, using `with` to open your file. The advantage of using this construct is that it will automatically *close* your file for you when you are done, or if you encounter an exception.

```
   def printOutput(start, end, makeList):
      if start == end == None:
          return
      else:
          out_fname = 'out'+uniprotID+'.txt'
          with open(out_fname, 'w') as outputFile:
              while start <= end:
                  print start
                  print end
                  inRange = makeList[start]
                  start += 1
                  outputFile.write(inRange)
```

Otherwise, you would have to remember to *explicitly* close the file with `outputFile.close()`.

Comment: i am just curious, what would happend if file doesnt close?

Comment: @ChadD  In some instances all of your data won't get written to the output file. Your output is collected in a buffer before it gets written to a file. If your program doesn't close the file, this buffer may not get flushed. Here is a recent problem on SO dealing with just this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398471/python-not-writing-full-string-to-file -- It *is* important you close your file(s). The nice thing about `with` is that it relieves you from having to worry about it.

Comment: thank you very much it works. is there a way that i can have the print out of index number that makeList print to my outputfile on the console?

Comment: yes, i switched the order of outputFile.write(inRange) and start +=1. However, it still print makeList of index +1 of the actual value. I don't understand why would this happen.

Comment: @ChadD I am not sure I understand your question, but you can still use `print` inside your loop as before to display values to the console. Writing to a file at the same time does not prevent you from doing this.

Comment: so for example my start =10 and end =20... the result i got from the outputFile is makeList[11]...makeList[21] instead of makeList[10]...makeList[20]. Do you know how to fix this? thanks in advance